# Low-Pass filter for unity compass

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an Geo location application in unity. i am trying to figure out the north direction, unity compass provides the directional data but it is very noisy.. can anyone help me with the Low Pass filter for compass data.

Comment: Hi Vishal_, you should check Kalman Filter; here is an example that you can try;

https://gist.github.com/GLeBaTi/011f338e037124553217abfda531d1e7

Comment: It's easy to do this but you need to edit  your question and post your current compass code in order to get help. This will make sure that you won't get the-same answer with the code that you're already using.